# Haskell - Calculate sum of functions by creating a higher class function

Tags: function, haskell, lambda

**Without the usage of imported code** (i can use head, `tail`,`init`,`last`,`filter`,`map`,`fold`, `.` , generally basic haskell functions ) 
I want to create a higher-order function int ,type `hof :: [Integer->Integer]->(Integer->Integer)` , with `hof s = \n ->....` (using lambda)
that implements the following math formula

[image: badly cropped photo of hand-written formula]
(sorry, it is hand-written)

Need some basic guidence for starting , i thought about implementing a recoursive call each time of the hof function , which hof itself should implement a changed math formula(which i given) suitable for recursive tail calls.

some results that should be produced :

```
Main> map (hof [(+1)]) [1..10]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

Main> map (hof [(+1),(+2)]) [1..10]
[3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,15,16]

Main> map (hof [(2^),(2^),(2^),(2^),(2^)]) [5..12]
[42,85,170,341,682,1364,2728,5456]

Main> map (hof [(*2),(+100),(^3),negate,(mod 100)]) [24..40]
[2768,3151,3567,4020,4509,5038,5609,6221,6876,7575,8322,9117,9960,10855,11805,
12806,13863]

Main> map (hof [(mod 100),negate,(+100),(^3),(*2)]) [24..40]
[1181,1351,1562,1767,1989,2230,2490,2771,3071,3395,3774,4145,4539,4958,5402,5873,6369]

Main> map (hof [(‘mod‘ i) | i<-[50..100] ]) [1000..1030]
[23,24,27,28,30,32,35,36,39,40,37,38,40,41,44,45,47,48,52,53,55,31,33,35,37,39,42,
45,46,48,47]
```

Thanks for reading !

Comment: What problems are you having with implementing this?

Comment: i havent find a way to start implementing this , i could do it if it was for example a polynom instead of that math formula which contians f(n) functions

Comment: How would you write a function that evaluates a polynomial?

Comment: So, what attempt have you made?

Comment: polynom (h:t) = \x -> h + x * ((poly t) x)

Comment: In particular, you need access to the index i, so a simple recursion will not suffice

Comment: What did you attempt? What happened when you tried? Include this in your question, not the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a list of functions:

```
fs = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5] -- or more
```

Now, for each value `i` from 0 to infinity, we want to apply a function from `fs` to a corresponding `n - i`, then divide that value by 2<sup>i</sup>, and we want to sum the resulting floors.

```
hof fs = \n -> sum [ fi (n-i) `div` (2^i) | (fi, i) <- zip fs [0..]]
```

Even though `[0..]` is an infinite list, the result of `zip fs [0..]` is finite, limited by the length of `fs`.

To avoid repeated multiplications for each successive power of 2, use the `iterate` function to compute a sequence of them to zip along with `fs` and `[0..]`

```
hof fs = \n -> sum [fi (n-i) `div` k | (fi, i, k) <- zip3 fs [0..] (iterate (*2) 1)]
```

Comment: You could also `zip3 (iterate (2*) 1) ...`, which I believe saves having to `2^i` from scratch each time.

Comment: works great ! Seems like magic to me . Yea i understand the infinite lists implemetion part , just this code (fi, i) <- zip fs in complicated for me , putting the fi in the generator. Also i cant use zip or zip3 , cause i should only use very basic haskell functions , but i think i should be able to find somewhere the source code for it.

Comment: Not sure why you could use `fold` but not `zip`.

Comment: I believe there's a language extension somewhere that lets you replace `zip` by something like `[ ... | fi <- fs | i <- [0 ..] ]`.

Comment: ParallelListComprehensions is the extension

Comment: @A Tayler thank you for your input , i will check it out. In the meantime i found this https://gist.github.com/ijoshsmith/8cf1cff07b62fdf14056 custom imp , works fine

Comment: @TeoGoltsios you do know that you can just copy code from Prelude and/or Data.List right? eg. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zip3

Comment: @ATayler i didnt no . Thanks for the info